# How do I remotely produce a message to kafka broker which is present in cloud?

Tags: apache-kafka

There's a cloud machine Whose public ip is known in which kafka broker is up and running. How do I produce and consume a message to this kafka broker from my laptop.

Comment: I have tried changing advertised listeners and listeners, but I am not sure what values I need to give exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Open Kafka ports and connect directly via TCP or use Kafka REST proxy

https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on the address bar.
2. Type `google.com`, and enter.
3. Within the textbox, write ***kafka producer consumer example***, and enter.
4. There will be plenty of resources showing you how.

Comment: That is not my question. The broker and Zookeeper is running on cloud machine but I need to produce from my local machine.